# WebRTC onicecandidate NEVER fires in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

My webrtc web app never fies onicecandidate.
When I look into my local(Webrtc Object) object,  localdescription and remotedescription are setted. 
In firefox, it fires onicecandidate but event.candidate is null

I tried to solve this problem for several hours, but I couldn't

Can anybody solve this problem?

How can I make onicecandidate event to be fired?

```
  let local = new RTCPeerConnection();
  let remote = new RTCPeerConnection();
  try {
    local.createOffer().then(function(sdp) {
      console.log("Offer Created by Local: " + sdp.sdp);
      local.setLocalDescription(sdp);
      remote.setRemoteDescription(sdp);

      remote.createAnswer().then(function(sdp){
        console.log("Answer Created by Remote: " + sdp.sdp);
        remote.setLocalDescription(sdp);
        local.setRemoteDescription(sdp);
        local.onicecandidate = localicecandidate;
        remote.onicecandidate = remoteicecandidate;

        let channel = local.createDataChannel("channel");
        channel.onopen = function(event) {
          console.log("Channel opened");
        }
        channel.onmessgae = function(event) {
          console.log(event.data);
        }

        remote.ondatachannel = function(event) {
          let channel = event.channel;
          channel.onopen = function(event) {
            channel.send("Hi!");
          }
        }

        function localicecandidate (event) {
          console.log("Local got new Ice Candidate: " + event.candidate);
          remote.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }
        function remoteicecandidate (event) {
          console.log("Remote got new Ice Candidate: " + event);
          local.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
        }

      }); 
    })
  }

  catch (e) {
    console.log("Got Error" + e);
  }
```

Comment: onmessgae -- you have a typo there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling createDataChannel before calling createOffer so you SDP contains no m=lines. Without m-lines there is nothing for ICE to negotiate.

Move `let channel = local.createDataChannel("channel");` before createOffer.